# Proper GTK environment without desktop environment

Tags: linux, desktop, gtk

I'm using Xmonad on archlinux, without a desktop environment installed. I managed to set the Numix theme for GTK2 with this `~/.gtkrc-2.0`

```
gtk-icon-theme-name="Numix"
gtk-theme-name="Numix"
```

and GTK3 with `export GTK_THEME=Numix` in my `~/.xinitrc`. For some reason setting it in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` didn't work:

```
[Settings]
gtk-icon-theme-name = "Numix"
gtk-theme-name = "Numix"
gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans 10"
```

So, how can I get GTK to load the config file?

And, in general, what are things that a desktop environment sets up (like environment variables, config files, or even daemons) that GTK applications usually rely on?

That is, other than display and window managers, and a set of applications, what, if any, "glue" functionality does a DE like GNOME provide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this post and is trying to customize on a non desktop environment setup, Check out [lxappearance](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXAppearance#:%7E:text=LXAppearance%20is%20the%20standard%20theme,to%20enable%20the%20accessibility%20features.) which can be found on any standard package managers. It's super lightweight and it lets you setup any GTK theme you like without having to install a desktop environment. cheers